# Is there any way to control mouse through java?

Tags: java

I want to control mouse by robot class. Just move to left or right. Meanwhile I run eclipse with administrator status. Here is my code below.

```
public class ControlMouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            robot.delay(1000);  // this one is the same...
            robot.mouseMove(100, 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("e = " + e.toString());
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("e = " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems doesn't work and no error or exception message. Dose any one may give me some advice? Thank you. The development environment is window 7. And I expect I can see the mouse cursor or traces will change. But I can’t.

Comment: Mateusz: the error being there is no error, the cursor just doesn't move.
@apss1943: have you tried with other coördinates? The code seems correct to me.

Comment: What were you expecting? (0,0) IS the top left of the screen...

Comment: It works for me as well without any errors what so ever.
You might want to add extra moves so you can see the cursor move over the screen.

Comment: @Adam I assume he means on his pc, his cursor is not moving.

Comment: @apss 1943: Do you run on Windows or Linux?

Comment: On Windows 7 at least this works as expected. Perhaps you should add a robot.delay(250) after the mouse move call so the application doesn't end in a split second, or better yet actually startup a Swing GUI or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to put some delay and then check. without delay / sleep, *sometimes*  GUI elements cannot be handled properly. You might even miss the event.

```
class ControlMouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            robot.mouseMove(0, 0);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            robot.mouseMove(100, 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("e = " + e.toString());
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("e = " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will work. It will move to `0,0` and then to `0,100`

Comment: it seems do nothing. i can find any change.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - The OP *added delay* and edited his question based on my answer. Check the edit history :).. I once faced a similar issue, the mouse cursor was not moving when i called `mouseMove()`, turns out the calls were being ignored. Adding *delay* fixed the issue.

Comment: @TheLostMind So long as I'm not going completely crazy ;)